# Does summing up word embedding vectors in ML destroy their meaning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

For example, I have a paragraph which I want to classify in a binary manner. But because the inputs have to have a fixed length, I need to ensure that every paragraph is represented by a uniform quantity.

One thing I've done is taken every word in the paragraph, vectorized it using GloVe word2vec and then summed up all of the vectors to create a "paragraph" vector, which I've then fed in as an input for my model. In doing so, have I destroyed any meaning the words might have possessed? Considering these two sentences would have the same vector:
"My dog bit Dave" & "Dave bit my dog", how do I get around this? Am I approaching this wrong?

What other way can I train my model? If I take every word and feed that into my model, how do I know how many words I should take? How do I input these words? In the form of a 2D array, where each word vector is a column?

I want to be able to train a model that can classify text accurately. 
Surprisingly, I'm getting a high (>90%) for a relatively simple model like RandomForestClassifier just by using this summing up method. Any insights?

Edit: One suggestion I have received is to instead featurize my data as a 2D array where each word is a column, on which a CNN could work. Another suggestion I received was to use transfer learning through the huggingface transformer to get a vector for the whole paragraph. Which one is more feasible?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to train a model that can classify text accurately. Surprisingly, I'm getting a high (>90%) for a relatively simple model like RandomForestClassifier just by using this summing up method. Any insights?

If you look up papers on aggregating word embeddings you'll find out that this in fact occurs sometimes, especially if the texts are shorter.

> What other way can I train my model? If I take every word and feed that into my model, how do I know how many words I should take? How do I input these words? In the form of a 2D array, where each word vector is a column?

Have you tried keyword extraction? It can alleviate some of the problems with averaging

> In doing so, have I destroyed any meaning the words might have
>   possessed?

As you remarked, you throw out information on word order. But that's not even the worst part: most of the times for longer documents if you embed everything the mean will get dominated by common words ("how", "like", "do" et c). BTW see my answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312206/can-i-apply-word2vec-to-find-document-similarity/320657#320657)

Other than that, one trick I've seen is to average word vectors, but subtract first principal component of PCA on word embedding matrix. For details you can see for example [this repo](https://github.com/PrincetonML/SIF) which also links to the paper (BTW [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.13494.pdf) suggests you can ignore "Smooth Inverse Frequency" stuff since principal component reduction does the useful part).

Comment: Any thoughts on gensim Doc2Vec embeddings? That essentially does the whole job for me, but I haven't implemented it.